# Appium issue while running on Windows

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium

I've downgraded Android studio thinking that the emulator 25.1.16 will work with Appium 1.4.16.1

It was working fine in Android 1.5 but I upgraded to Android Studio 2 along with the Emulator 2 and I started getting the error below.

Anyone have idea on how to get by on this?  I know there's a patch done for iOS in github but I don't see any for Windows version.  Thanks in advance

ISSUE:

> info: [debug] Telnet command got response: a[K[Dav[K[D[Davd[K[D[D[Davd [K[D[D[D[Davd n[K[D[D[D[D[Davd na[K[D[D[D[D[D[Davd nam[K[D[D[D[D[D[D[Davd name[K

[Appium Issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ3r6.png)

Comment: Hi @gerechtigkeit please past your full log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by reverting back the version of the Emulator < 2.0 for now.  Appium start seeing my Emulators from my AVD Manager.  Once Appium is updated for Windows version; there's no other choice than stick to older version until then.

Answer (score 0):

my fix was to download installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads  (or the right package for your platform) and then 
copy only the tools folder from \Local\Android\android-sdk to the location where you use the tools folder via appium